# Why is the ViewFormPagesLockDown Feature required for my site template? SP2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I have a site template that we use for creating Project Workspaces. The template was developed by another person who has now left the Company. It was working fine until I was doing some work on external sharing, and realized I had to deactivate the ViewFormPagesLockDown feature in order to be able to share folders externally. So I did.

Then I realized that the site template stopped working. The error Message said that it required the ViewFormPagesLockDown Feature. After downloading and inspecting the wsp for the site template, I can see that it indeed lists this feature (ID="{7c637b23-06c4-472d-9a9a-7c175762c5c4}") in the ONet.xml file. The problem is that I have no idea why.

I cannot activate the feature, because it prevents folder sharing. I will probably end up creating a New site template from scratch and hope that this feature is not required. But I would very much like to know why and how this feature is added to the requirements of the site template, and if possible, how to remove it.

Comment: After fiddling around a bit, I might have found the answer. I activated the feature, created a New, empty sub site from the site template. Then I deactivated the feature, and saved the site as a New site template. After the inspecting the New site template, the lockdown feature is gone. So it looks like it includes the features already activated as required when creating a New site template. I find this a bit strange, because then there is no way to actually know which features are required, it just assumes that all features are required.

Comment: How did you disable ViewFormPagesLockDown Feature in SPO?

Comment: Site settings/site actions/manage site features. That particular feature is only available in Publishing sites.

Comment: Correct location is Site Settings/Site Action/Manage Site Collection Features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the Comment, it seems like all features that are active at the time of creation of the template will be required. So to fix it, deactivate the feature and create a New site template.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the subsite of the template, you can just save it again as template, and the new template should work.